# Concatenate every column

Tags: mysql

This is a subset of my table:

```
first | last | city
Fred  | NULL | LA
Mary  | Jane | Boulder
```

How do I concatenate every column without specifying the column names? (I have 20 columns in my REAL table but I don't want to have to type them in). I have:

```
SELECT CONCAT('first', ',' , 'last' , ',' , 'city') FROM table; # How do I do it without specifying the column names????
```

desired result:

```
Fred,NULL,LA
Mary,Jane,Boulder
```

Comment: Do it in your application, not in a SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: you can with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and dynamic sql, but that is a really bad idea.